# changing a different column information depending on time in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, date, triggers, status, datatrigger

I have a to-do table.  This table has a job end date and a status column with a boolean value.  my question is i want the status part to change from true to false when the date value is for example march 1st 2022.  how can I do it?

Select to_do_date, status from to_do

in February 18

to_do         status
03-01-2022    true

in March 1

to_do         status
03-01-2022    false

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to display a changed status, without actually changing it in the table, you can ignore the status column and produce it by comparing the `to_do_date` with the current date.

For example:

```
select to_do_date, to_do_date < current_date as status from to_do;
```